# SharePoint workflow weird behaviour for workflow running when item is modified

Tags: 2013, office-365, nintex

I have a workflow that gets triggered when an item is modified ( tried both nintex and sharepoint designer)

The workflow context works when the creator edits the item

But when someone else modifies the item, the current item is not working in Nintex

It says item does not exist in the status

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Question: Does the mentioned list has versioning activated? if so check on the list settings who can see the drafts, looks like you have the "Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)" option or something related to content approval.

If I don't recall wrongly the workflow context executes using the user that launches the wf (in both cases, for Nintex and SP designer wfs) so by your description looks like something worthy to check.

Good luck!

Comment: Versioning is not enabled. Workflow works only when person who created the item edits it! It fails otherwise

Comment: Ok, then my only other hinch for this would be to ensure that the item is checked in...(and if you had previously on your workflow actions a check in / out add a commit action just after that operation.